# How to add cookies in chrome browser with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi i want to add cookies in chrome browser with python
This is my cookies :

```
.adsniper.ru    TRUE    /   FALSE   2269406350  uuid3   IiQxMGQzMjE5ZS01NTk2LTExZWMtODZlMC0wMDI1OTBjMDY0N2M*
    .lkqd.net   TRUE    /   FALSE   1670222352  lkqdid  m7UBxkXbzhE
    .lkqd.net   TRUE    /   FALSE   1670222352  lkqdidts    1638686358
    .gumgum.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1670222352  vst a_df407ab4-ed80-4859-a9c1-fa7505b02c07
    pool.admedo.com FALSE   /   FALSE   1678927896  tuuid   4d83edc3-290e-4346-8954-1ce8e7a09c6f
    pool.admedo.com FALSE   /   FALSE   1670222353  c   1638686358
    .crwdcntrl.net  TRUE    /   FALSE   1662012534  _cc_dc  2
    .lkqd.net   TRUE    /   FALSE   1670222353  sr758   1||1638686359
    .sportradarserving.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   1678927894  zuuid   2b758206-8cfe-4814-9873-06e2666f398b
    .sportradarserving.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   1670222353  c   1638686359
    .adentifi.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1701758360  adtheorent[cuid]    cuid_13a77643-5596-11ec-8402-12bc57b19708
    .targeting.unrulymedia.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   1680253331  _rxuuid %7B%22rx_uuid%22%3A%22RX-7b86d8e4-08ac-446d-acdc-998f01853c48-004%22%7D
    .sportradarserving.com  TRUE    /   FALSE   1678927894  zuuid_k 1
    .tynt.com   TRUE    /   FALSE   1670222360  uid Ko4iVGGsXp4yKSonIObEfQ==
```